# Can I use assembly code generated with gcc/llvm/clang in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, clang, llvm, vectorization

I'm having performance problems with some C code that I compile with Visual Studio 2017 (even after rewriting the code using intrinsics, the performance is not great because the compile seems to add a move operation before every vector addition or multiplication). However, I get very good assembly code from clang/llvm using its vectorization features. Now, if I could actually use the assembly code from LLVM and add it to my Visual Studio project, that would be great, and would save me a lot of time in the long run.

I know that I can choose the output syntax with gcc/llvm/clang. The problem of course is that the .s file that is generated has a very different structure from the .asm file that Visual Studio expects (constant definitions, macros, etc.).

Does anybody know a solution to this problem? Either on the code generation side or in Visual Studio?

Comment: Probably not the ideal solution, but you could use inline assembly and just paste the code that LLVM generated into the VS source files..

Comment: You can of course generate a standalone function in an object file and link it. Assuming it doesn't use any external stuff, but sounds like you are doing computations so that might work.

Comment: Good point, and certainly an option for just 2-3 functions. I'll just have to find out by hand which parts I have to copy and which ones are for example just saving register states at the beginning of the function. Furthermore I have to find out what all the macros do that are in the assembly code. However, in the future I'll have more code to maintain for different platforms, and it would be great to have a more automatized solution.

Comment: Jester, are .o files generated by LLVM the same format as the Visual Studio .obj files?

Comment: No idea about LLVM, but mingw-gcc can produce such object files. I expect LLVM exists for windows too?

Comment: LLVM has a Windows compatibility mode, so I imagine this would work wondrously. Are you *certain*, though, that there is no way to tweak the existing C code so that MSVC generates sufficient quality output? Perhaps you should consider asking a question here about that.

Comment: Is adapting to clang as compiler a viable solution? Modern VS allows to switch to clang as a compiler, retaining all other features: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/03/07/use-any-c-compiler-with-visual-studio/. If you can't use clang for all source code files, you would have to move the offending code into its own (library-) project and link to that.

Comment: I'm sure that if I put enough effort in it, I could getting code to work sufficiently well using MSVC, too. But the goal is to remain reasonably platform-independent. Currently I'm using LLVM to compile parallelized code for Intel and ARM architectures, and it works wonderfully, though some of the wrappers I use are platform-specific. The code looks really clean though. If I have to rewrite everything with intrinsics and #ifdefs, it will mess up everything a lot. That's why I'm looking for something as automatic as possible.

Comment: @antipattern: yes, using Clang could be an option, if it's a clang implementation that is based on LLVM, because the vector types I'm using seem to be specific to LLVM (as far as I know, there's a version of clang that actually uses MSVC as a backend).

Comment: Actually, if I could find a way to define float32x4 and float32x8 data types and do arithmetic operations on them (both vector-vector and scalar-vector), that would help me a lot, as it would be easy then to emulate the behavior of LLVM. But I guess that would be an entirely different question.

Comment: @FritzMenzer Not worth an answer, but i found this: https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?54770-Using-Clang-to-compile-on-Windows. Unter the header "Cool stuff" it states that "Clang now has full compatibility with Microsoft's C++ object format. This means it can seamlessly link with code compiled with VC++, such as third party libraries."

Comment: From that I would assume that the previously mentioned way (make .o from clang and just link to those with cl.exe) might work